# How to make generator link with JavaScript like on autoddl.com site

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want make generator link with JavaScript, similar to what this site did: autoddl.com.

I just want to change the domain only, for example:

**www.qwerty.com**/detail/dsa8e2w2a1
to
**www.download.com**/detail/dsa8e2w2a1
~

> /detail/dsa8e2w2a1 < is unchanged, only the primary domain being changed.

Please help, I've tried searching it up but dont know the keyword.

Comment: try this javascript code **window.location.href.replace('qwerty.com','download.com')**

Answer (score 0):

Split the url using split method, which will create an array , now replace the the first value of the array with the new `host` name and then use `array#join` method to form the new string.

```js
var originalAdd = "www.qwerty.com/detail/dsa8e2w2a1";
var newDomainName = "www.download.com";
var x = originalAdd.split("/");
x[0] = newDomainName;
console.log(x.join('/'));
```

Alternatively you can also `location.host` which will give `"www.qwerty.com"` & `location.pathname` which will give `"/detail/dsa8e2w2a1"` & replace `location.host` with the new host

Comment: sry im not really know about javascript, i just know about how to edit html, idk javacript language, ty for help me, but can u give me complete javascript with form? like this > https://image.ibb.co/mdCCfn/Screenshot_18.png